# List available downloads per order in WooCommerce?

Tags: download, woocommerce

I know I can already list the full array of available downloads on the My Account page for a user, but what about filtering them out on a per order basis?  As in...when a user views an order, the list of downloads available to them for that order are listed rather than every download for every order.  I'm having trouble figuring out the right code that will filter them out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WooCommerce don't have this kind of functionality nor any plugin which can fit your purpose.
Have check on filters to add downloads of that products below the respective orders but even filter nor actions where found.

Then a final way of achieving this is through a little customization which you have to code.

To achieve your requirement you have to override woocommerce template here its woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php. Check on tutorials to override woocommerce templates in your custom plugin/child theme.

After you override, customize the new code and add you magic code in the loop of orders to display there respective download below each order.

Let me know it this solution works for you.

Comment: Well editing that page won't help because it calls a different template into it for downloads.  The downloads template simply calls an array of available downloads for the user.  I'm just trying to figure out a creative edit to the array code that adds one more filter into the mix so that only the downloads for the order you are viewing are showing.